# Проблема с запуском docker-compose и docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Делаю `docker-compose up` для докер-файла, который находится здесь же, в этой же папке и получаю:

> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it
> running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение 1

Одно из решений -- запускаться из-под рута. Сделайте

```
sudo su
docker-compose up
```

Или же

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

## Решение 2

Другим решением является добавить юзера в группу docker, предварительно создав её, если её нет:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Создать группу можно так:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```